# Branchless way to map 0 to any nonzero value while leaving other values alone?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation, branch

I am trying to find the the fastest possible implementation of this function:

```
uint16_t forbid_zero(uint16_t x)
{
    if(x == 0)
        return SOMETHING_NONZERO;
    return x;
}
```

It doesn't matter what SOMETHING_NONZERO is, as long as it's not zero. Any value other than zero should pass through unmodified. What's the fastest bit hackery for doing this? I assume there's some nice branchless way.

For context I have an algorithm in my critical path where zero as an input value will trigger infinite looping and other bad behavior, and I'm curious if it's possible for me to massage the input to always be nonzero without branching to check for 0.  The consequence of passing an incorrect nonzero value to the algorithm is not nearly as bad; the mistake will be caught by checks that already have to exist at other layers, so mapping 0 to any other value is good enough.

Comment: Perhaps `return -!x|x;`

Comment: "I assume there's some nice branchless way." Well, you can't take a piece of C code and predict how it will end up being executed in a processor (unless you are extremely experienced in such stuff). You need to compile the code and investigate the generated binary. And even there it's difficult to predict the performance due to all the tricks used by the processor so you'll probably have to do profiling in the end.

Comment: A branch which is completely predictable is, on a modern CPU, almost free. Avoiding branches is mostly relevant for unpredictable branches.

Comment: I appreciate the point you both are making, but it's unnecessary for someone to make it on every single performance question. If somebody knows to ask for branch free code it's safe to assume they have a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible implementation is:

```
uint16_t forbid_zero(uint16_t x)
{
    return x | !x;
}
```

Which the Compile Explorer shows [x86-64 gcc 8.2 compiles to](https://godbolt.org/z/6_pww0):

```
forbid_zero(unsigned short):
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testw   %di, %di
        sete    %al
        orl     %edi, %eax
        ret
```

However even the implementation you give in the question [compiles to branchless code using a conditional move instruction](https://godbolt.org/z/hj3B1o) with the same compiler:

```
forbid_zero(unsigned short):
        testw   %di, %di
        movl    $1, %eax
        cmovne  %edi, %eax
        ret
```

...and of course there's no guarantee that `!x` won't be compiled to a branch, either.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods.

0. Direct.

```
unsigned is_all_zeros(uint16_t x)
{
  return x ? x : 0;
}
```

1. Negate, invert, and shift.

```
unsigned is_all_zeros(uint16_t x)
{
  uint32_t y = -x; // Zero: MSB=0, non-zeros: MSB=1
  y = ~y;          // Zero: MSB=1, non-zeros: MSB=0
  return y >> 31;  // Zero: 1, non-zeros: 0
}
```

2. Invert, popcnt, and shift.

```
unsigned is_all_zeros(uint16_t x)
{
  x = -x;  // Zero: 16 '1's, non-zeros: 15 or less '1's
  unsigned c = __builtin_popcount(x);  // Zero: 16, non-zeros: 15 or less
  return c >> 4; // Zero: 1, non-zeros: 0
}
```

3. Invert, inc, and shift.

```
unsigned is_all_zeros(uint16_t x)
{
  x = -x;  // Zero: 0xffff, non-zeros: less than 0xffff
  unsigned c = (unsigned)(x) + 1;  // Zero: 0x10000, non-zeros: 0xffff or less
  return c >> 4; // Zero: 1, non-zeros: 0
}
```